# querySelectorAll doesn't find element in Woocommerce single product page

Tags: javascript, php, html, woocommerce

Trying to work with single product gallery navigation. This is Woocommerce website.

[image: product gallery navigation]

Here is HTML code of this area:

[image]

I'm sorry, but I can't copy it from page source, because there is no such piece of code.
I am trying to get `ol.flex-control-nav` element using this code:

```js
console.log('ok');
let addImagesLength = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-product-gallery ol');
console.log(addImagesLength);
```

Using "ok" in console log to be sure, that code is correct before it. So everything what I get in log is empty node list. I assume, that `ol.flex-control-nav` element is appearing after `.js` file loads.
One thing what also I would like to mention is that product gallery navigation section is called in `wwocommerce.php` page using this snippet:

```html
function web_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'web_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

So I assume, that this piece of code loads gallery navigation after `.js` file was fully loaded. Was trying to enqueue separate `.js` file after this PHP code, but result is the same. If it is so, then how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but why don't you just use document.querySelectorAll("ol.flex-control-nav")?

Comment: There is no difference technically. The result is the same. I can't explain why, I just do so.

Comment: Have you already tried adding 'defer' to the script you're trying to include? Like <script src="./my/script/" defer></script> ?

Comment: I call the script using `wp_enqueue_script`. So I didn't find the way how to add `defer` into this function so far. But I already solved the problem by using `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by adding putting all function into `window.onload`.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('ok');
    let addImagesLength = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-control-nav');
    console.log(addImagesLength);
}
```